# Python Multiprocessing map_async

Tags: python, asynchronous, dictionary, multiprocessing

I’d like to skip results that are returned from [`map_async`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map_async). They are growing in memory but I don’t need them.

Here is some code:

```
def processLine(line):
    #process something
    print "result"
pool = Pool(processes = 8)
for line in sys.stdin:
    lines.append(line)
    if len(lines) >= 100000:
        pool.map_async(processLine, lines, 2000)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

When I have to process file with hundreds of millions of rows, the python process grows in memory to a few gigabytes. How can I resolve that?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

Your code has a bug:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    lines.append(line)
    if len(lines) >= 100000:
        pool.map_async(processLine, lines, 2000)
```

This is going to wait until `lines` accumulates more than 100000 lines. After that, `pool.map_async` is being called on the entire list of 100000+ lines **for each additional line**.

It is not clear exactly what you are really trying to do, but
if you don't want the return value, use `pool.apply_async`, not `pool.map_async`. Maybe something like this:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def processLine(line):
    #process something
    print "result"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool(processes = 8)
    for line in sys.stdin:
        pool.apply_async(processLine, args = (line, ))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you're right. There is some bug

I mean:

```
def processLine(line):
  #process something
  print "result"
  pool = Pool(processes = 8)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  for line in sys.stdin:
    lines.append(line)
    if len(lines) >= 100000:
      pool.map_async(processLine, lines, 2000)
      lines = [] #to clear buffer
  pool.map_async(processLine, lines, 2000)
  pool.close()
  pool.join()
```

I used map_async because it has configurable chunk_size so it is more efficient if there are lots of lines which processing time is quite short.