# Why multiprocessing is slow

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, multiprocessing, primes

I just started reading about multiprocessing for the sake of speeding up my programs.
hence, i wrote two basic examples to extract prime numbers from a list of random numbers.

Example 1: Using multiprocessing

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from random import randrange
import time

def randomList(q, size, nmax):
    l = []
    r = randrange(2, nmax)
    for i in range(size):
        while r in l: # avoid replicating numbers
            r = randrange(2, nmax)
        l.append(r)
        q.put(r)

def checkPrime(numbers, prime):
    if numbers.qsize():
        n = numbers.get()
        count = 0 # divisors counter
        d = 2 # divisor
        while not count and d<=n/2:
            if n%d:
                d+=1
            else:
                count+=1
        if not count:
            prime.put(n)

if __name__=="__main__":
    numbers = Queue()
    prime = Queue()
    randomList(numbers, 50, 1000) # 50 number | 100 max value
    t1 = time.time()
    while numbers.qsize():
        for i in range(10): # Running 10 processes 
            p=Process(target=checkPrime, args=(numbers, prime))
            p.start()
            p.join()
    t2 = time.time()
    primes = []
    for i in range(prime.qsize()):
        primes.append(prime.get())
    print("[+] Prime numbers:")
    print(primes)
    print("[+] Time elapsed:"+str(t2-t1))
```

Output:

```
[+] Prime numbers:
[17, 227, 389, 593, 953, 757]
[+] Time elapsed:9.41699981689
```

Exemple 2: the same example 1 but without multiprocessing

```
[...]
    while numbers.qsize():
        checkPrime(numbers, prime)
[...]
```

Output:

```
[+] Prime numbers:
[193, 227, 241, 439, 499, 877, 479, 743, 929]
[+] Time elapsed:0.00999999046326
```

So, multiprocessing makes this program (specifically maybe) hugely slower than without using it.
Any explanation? am I using it the wrong way?

Comment: cannot replicate your issue. multiprocessing  returns `Time elapsed:0.311047077179`

Comment: your operations are too inexpensive compared to the overhead of multiprocessing?

Answer (score 3):

I'm thinking your method of multiprocessing is poor.  Rather than splitting the work into 10 processes and starting them all up at once, you're starting a single process at a time and each one is doing a single unit of work then exiting.  Your implementation will create (and then destroy) 50 processes over its lifetime, which creates a lot of overhead.

You're also joining the processes immediately after starting them, which will make it so you're never actually running multiple processes.  The join makes it wait for the child process to finish before continuing.

Finally, there's gotta be a better way to return results that using a queue and getting a single value at a time.  If you can start each process at once with a set of work to do and then return the results in list to the master thread, you could reduce the overhead of using the Queue.

Comment: 1) Before asking the question, I tried joining the 10 processes after starting them and this made things worse, it became memory and CPU intense, the computer freezes and i had to restart it again. 2) One should use Queues when working with multiprocessing and multithreading because it's process and thread safe.

Comment: Of COURSE starting/joining 10 processes is going to be CPU intense (Unless you have more than 10 CPU cores).  You're giving it 10 things to do simultaneously.  That's kind of the point of multiprocessing.  Your current implementation is *NOT* actually doing any multiprocessing, yet is being hit by every bit of overhead that is involved with multiprocessing.  Queues are useful for multiprocessing because they're process safe, sure, but there's overhead involved in every transfer to/from the queue.  If possible, you should minimize the number of transfers and maximize the size of each transfer.

Comment: I understand your code just fine.  You're generating 50 random numbers between 2 and 1000 and putting them all in a queue and then trying to figure out which of them are prime, and you're trying to speed it up with multiprocessing, but your code is simply wrong and is NOT multiprocessing as written.  You're joining the new process immediately after starting it, which will prevent more processes from spawning until the new process finishes, effectively preventing you from doing actual multiprocessing.  Also, your method of checking for prime numbers should bail out as soon as a divisor is found

Comment: Obviously, you didn't understand the multiprocessing part of my code. you don't need to write an explanation of it in the next comment because i already know how it works. Plus, i DID MENTION why i MUST join the process after starting it...

Answer (score 1):

Your `for i in range()` is waiting for the process to finish when you `.join()` it.  So, basically, you're spawning a new process, which consumes the queue and reports the result, then your spawning 9 other processes to check an empty queue.

**`.join()`**

> Block the calling thread until the process whose join() method is called terminates or until the optional timeout occurs.

Pools are an easier way to do the same thing.
Check this answer for using `map_async()` with a pool of workers:

[Python Multiprocessing map_async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13916786/python-multiprocessing-map-async)

Comment: I tried to use a pool of 10 workers, the program takes 6.3s when using "apply" method and 1.6s when using "apply_async". Still slow

Comment: As mentioned by Fabricator, the amount of data may not be significant to see a gain that would validate the overhead of starting up other processes.  You could try increasing your sample size by a factor of 100 or so.

Comment: I got 5s (multiprocess) vs 9s (single) using `randomList(numbers, 15000, 150000)`

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple rule in multiprocessing: if the work for splitting (create child tasks) + joining (join results, etc) for creating the multiprocessing > sequential time then your 'parallel' version will be inefficient respect to the sequential one. This is your case. Try to generate one million of numbers(keeping in 10 your number of processes) and you will see the difference.

Good coding tips by @Sohcahtoa82. Take them in mind as well.